# Using pfnNtQuerySystemInformation, how do I determine the process's architecture?

Tags: c++, process, enumeration

Hey there awesome people.
I'm working on a project that uses

```
pfnNtQuerySystemInformation (SystemProcessInformation, (PVOID)proc,
                                              bufferSize, &ReturnLength);
```

To enumerate processes and obtain their information.
However, this does not seem to be able to find out the architecture of the process.
If there is a way to do that, or if anyone has any suggestions, I would be grateful.
~P

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Hans Passant, `IsWow64Process()` was the answer for me.
It checks to see if the process specified with a provided handle is a 64 bit process or not, returns a boolean answer.